# ERROR [kaa_logging.c:803] (-6) - Failed to upload log bucket, id '1' (delivery error code '1')

Tags: kaa

I started the Kaa's demo Data Collection:

```
Sampled temperature 31 1483523282
Sampled temperature 27 1483523283
Sampled temperature 31 1483523284
Sampled temperature 26 1483523285
Sampled temperature 33 1483523286
Sampled temperature 32 1483523287
Sampled temperature 34 1483523288
Sampled temperature 27 1483523289
Sampled temperature 25 1483523290
Sampled temperature 27 1483523291
Sampled temperature 28 1483523292
Sampled temperature 32 1483523293
Sampled temperature 30 1483523294
Sampled temperature 34 1483523295
Sampled temperature 27 1483523296
Sampled temperature 27 1483523297
Sampled temperature 33 1483523298
Sampled temperature 34 1483523299
2017/01/04 9:48:19 [ERROR] [kaa_logging.c:803] (-6) - Failed to upload log bucket, id '1' (delivery error code '1')
```

What does this last line of error means ? From what i see , it looks to be failed to upload into database.

Would like to ask for the community's help! Your answers and solutions are very important to us !

Answer (score 0):

It is an internal log appender error. By default, the Data Collection demo uses the MongoDB appender. Check that the MongoDB on your sandbox is up and running:

```
sudo service --status-all | grep mongo
```

Comment: Actually i have tried the default Data collection demo where it submits temperature and timestamp into Mongodb . And it succeeded . i verified the data when i ssh into kaa and into mongo kaa where i would count the number of entries inside once i ran the data collection demo where the entry really did increase